# Textview not showing aftert couple of VISIBLE and INVISIBLE set

Tags: android, textview

First, I used animation to hide and show TextView. I saw that using animation costing memory. So I used another way:

`SetVisibility(VISIBLE)` and `SetVisibility(INVISIBLE)` with `TaskTimer`

it works well and it performs better considering the memory.

The **main issue** is that after a restarting the timer for many times, the TextView disappear.

I need to restart the app to get it back again!

this is the code snippet:

```
myTimerForAnimation = new Timer();
myTimerForAnimation.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() // run on ui thread
      {
          public void run() {
              counter++;
              if (counter < 7) {
                  if (counter % 2 == 1) {
                      list_textView[x].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                  } else {
                      list_textView[x].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                  }
              } else {
                  myTimerForAnimation.cancel();
                  myTimerForAnimation.purge();

                  list_textView[x].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              }
          }
      });
  }
}, 1000, 600);
```

Comment: where is `x` set? and is it changed in your code? Could be that when `x` = 3 for example it makes `list_textView[3]` invisible and then you increase `x` for example and then `list_textView[3]`  will never be visible again? If I were you I would do a Log of `x` after each `setVisibility`

Comment: list_textView is fixed, x is not changing. X is fixed for one of the TextViews @IvoBeckers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @EE66 for the loop idea, I used this code to solve my problem:

```
private void animateView(final View view){
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 7; counter++) {
            long delay = counter * 1000;
            if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    ;
                }, delay);
            } else {
                view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                    ;
                }, delay);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont use Timer use handler,something like this:

```
// init the runnables
// the runnable should be members
Handler hanlder = new Handler();//If you arent on the UI thread pass a correct looper

for (int i=1; i<7 ; i++){
  long delay = i * 1000;
  if (i%2==0)
  {
     handler.postDelayed(mVisibleRunnable,delay);
  }else{
     handler.postDelayed(mInVisibleRunnable,delay);
  }
}
```

Whereas the get runnablebs should be memebers because if u choose to cancel the callbacks then call

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Play with it. It should fix your issue.

Comment: I used timer because I can stop it and start it again at anytime. so by using your method, not chances for stopping it and restarting it. otherwise, it looks a good solution

Comment: can i use handler to posDelay 3 TextViews at the same time ?

Comment: there shouldnt be any issue

Comment: its not guaranteed that it will be visible in the end, is it?

Comment: A. Nothing is guaranteed in life.
B. in this case it should be visible because the last runnable is a visible one.